# JavaScript - after import (webmix) Uncaught ReferenceError: getJobData is not defined error

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack

I am using default **Laravel webmix settings**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix')

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

My app file looks like this:

```
import './components/functions'
import './components/search'
import './components/jobs'
import './components/pagination'

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

I want to access this function in the **pagination** (which is located in the **functions** file):

```
function getJobData() {

    let duration = []
    let jobTypes = []

    $.each($(".duration"), function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            duration.push($(this).val());
        }

    });

    $.each($(".jobTypes"), function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            jobTypes.push($(this).val());
        }

    });

    return {
        term: $('#search_address').val(),
        advancedSearch: $("#advanced_search").is(':checked'),
        profession: $('#search_profession').val(),
        duration: $('#search_duration').val(),
        jobTypes: jobTypes,
        radius: $('#search_radius').val(),
        new: $("#order_new").is(':checked'),
        open: $("#open").is(':checked'),
        expired: $("#expired").is(':checked'),
        jobStatus: $("input[name=jobStatus]").val(),
        duration: duration,
        page: $('.pageNumber.current').data('page')
    }
}
```

This is the code in the pagination file:

```
$('body').on('click', '.page-link', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    let $this     = $(this)
    let paginator = $(".paginator")

    console.log(getJobData)

    return;


    $.get($this.attr('link'),  getData(),
        function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        },
        "json"
    );

});
```

I am getting this error:

```
app.js:225 Uncaught ReferenceError: getJobData is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It is in the main **app.js** file (the code is at the begging of the topic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you need to export?

```
// functions.js (I think?)
export function getJobData
```

Then you would need to import it properly to use it:

```
// pagination.js
import { getJobData } from './functions'
```

So the pagination file would look like:

```
// pagination.js
import { getJobData } from './functions';

$('body').on('click', '.page-link', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    let $this     = $(this)
    let paginator = $(".paginator")

    console.log(getJobData)
...
```

**When you're working with modules, each module is responsible for its own imports.**

Comment: Export doesn't change anything (the same error is still there).

Comment: The pagination file is trying to execute the function, right? You'll have to import the function there instead of in app.js.

Comment: @Sasha if you follow this answer this **must** work. Even if it is not exactly what you demanded, this is the correct way to make imports. Inside your `functions.js` there must be an export statement like: `export function getJobData() { ...... }` which can be imported in your `pagination.js` file like so: `import { getJobData } from './functions'`

Comment: This solution works (importing in the pagination file) but I need it to be global, since I will use this function on several other places.

Comment: @Sasha nowadays the best way is to import it in every file you need that function (as long as you make not use of any frameworks like angular). I'd recommend **not** to put function definitions to a global scope

Comment: @Sasha I agree with @messerbill. Polluting the global scope can get hairy. However, if you want to use a global, you can do `global.getJobData = function() {...}`. Or if you're in the browser `window.getJobData = function() {...}`. Again, not recommended though. https://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices#Avoid_globals

Comment: @Sasha if your question is answered, would you mind accepting this answer?

Comment: @Corey No problem :)